# Removing captions in Swiper

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Under my images in my Swiper 'undefined' is being displayed.

[image]

This is inside the `<figcaption>` tag

How do I get rid of this? I do not want any captions in my swiper.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include a minimal, complete and verifyable example. See  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create one. Please provide a jsfiddle or some form of code sample. As is now, your question can't be answered as we have next to no information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper) is not adding the figcaption tag by itself (see [source code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=figcaption)).

This must be an element you added yourself, in your code. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can take a look at.